# How to enable ES8 on WebStorm 2016

Tags: webstorm, ecmascript-2017

I have installed the WebStorm 2016, but in the options (File > Settings > Language & Frameworks) I see only a few JavaScript language versions, the last one is ECMAScript 6.

Is there a way to add the ES8 or another JavaScript version in this version of the WebStorm?

Comment: actually there is no "ES8". under this term people typically mean some specific subset of [TC'39 proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). So just try selecting "ES6" and specify what syntax does not work for you.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to add another language version in this version of WebStorm?

Comment: do you have some statement that does not work after selecting "Ecmascript 6"? Inteliji team adds support for new language features even before they become _official_(stage 4). E.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27687 about private class fields support.

Comment: No, I don't in the current project that I am working on, I was just wondering if there is a way to add the new version of Javascript.

Comment: No, no way (unless you develop a plugin for that)